# replace "DynamicResource" with "StaticResource"

Tags: wpf, performance, expression-blend, dynamicresource, staticresource

To realize my application I have used a lot Blend3. When Blend3 wants to link a resource to another resource, it uses many times the link-type "DynamicResource". As I have understood (but I could have understood not well), the "Dynamic" links have sense only if I want to modify the links at runtime. In other cases they use more memory in vain. I don't want to modify anything at runtime, then the question is: have sense to replace "DynamicResource" with "StaticResource" in all my application?
Thank you!
Pileggi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248904/is-there-a-significant-performance-cost-to-dynamicresource-instead-of-staticresou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blend works better in design time with DynamicResource.  See:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/unnir/archive/2009/03/31/blend-wpf-and-resource-references.aspx

The money quote from that:

> **a) Should I use Static or Dynamic
> resource lookup?**
>
> Blend def. plays
> better with dynamic resource lookups.
> You could use a static resource lookup
> as long as the resource was not
> located or merged into App.xaml.
> People have raised concerns around
> performance issues with dynamic
> resource lookups (you pay for what you
> get). While that might be true, an
> interesting data point is that the
> Expression Blend source code uses a
> ton uses dynamic resource lookups for
> our own UI (of course, we too use
> static resource lookups in places
> where the resource would never change,
> or where it not possible to use a
> dynamic resource extension, for
> example non-DPs).

Comment: Thank you very much!
As Ian Oakes says in his post in the thread linked above by John Bowen, I found some errors at design time (also with the Visual Studio designer) when I have tried to replace "DynemicResource" with "StaticResource" in a usercontrol. I have decided to leave the Blend XAML code.