# Initializing static resource from code in C# WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, initialization, resourcedictionary

I have two WPF windows. Main one contains a grid bound to `ObservableCollection<Person>`. I can add and remove objects (people) from the list. I also have another window that I can show when I modify a person.

Person has three properties: Name, LastName and Age and properly implements INotifyPropertyChanged. In the new window I have 3 textboxes that are bound to a static resource Person called "person".

When I initialize new window I provide Person object to the constructor and then I want this person properties to be shown in the three textboxes.

When the code below looks like this everything works properly:

```
public ModifyPerson(Person modPerson)  
{  
    // ... some code  
    Person p = this.Resources["person"] as Person;  
    p.Name = modPerson.Name;  
    p.LastName = modPerson.LastName;  
    p.Age = modPerson.Age;  
}
```

However I prefer doing it like this:

```
public ModifyPerson(Person modPerson)  
{  
    // ... some code  
    this.Resources["person"] = modPerson;  
}
```

But then it does not work. (The resource is assigned properly, but the textboxes do not present the values of modPerson properties.

How can that be solved?

Comment: Can you show how your TextBoxes are defined?

Comment: Did you ensure that you NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Why are you using a `StaticResource` for this?

Answer (score 1):

Person is your `model` object. Instead of using as a `StaticResource` place it in a property that you bind to.

```
public ModifyPerson(Person modPerson)
{
    personToModify = modPerson;
}

private Person personToModify;

public Person PersonToModify
{
    get
    {
        return personToModify;
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding PersonToModify}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay" />
</StackPanel>
```

(I left out labels in order to be concise)

You could use `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource` but using either of those for your `Model` really isn't their intended purpose and instead you should use a `Binding`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [DynamicResource instead of StaticResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

in XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Age}"></TextBox>
```

in Code:
u need a copy for UI binding, like this,

```
public EditPlayerWindow(PlayerBO arg)
        : this() {
        this.source =arg;
        this.view = new PlayerBO();
        arg.CopyTo(this.view);
        this.DataContext = view;
    }
```

the CopyTo like:

```
public void CopyTo(PlayerBO player) {
player.Id = this.Id;
player.Name = this.Name;
player.CurrentPolicyVersion = this.CurrentPolicyVersion;
player.CreatedAt = this.CreatedAt;
player.UpdatedAt = this.UpdatedAt;
player.Description = this.Description;
player.MACAddress = this.MACAddress;
player.IPAddress = this.IPAddress;
player.Policy = Policy;
```

}

At last:

```
view.CopyTo(source);
```

then save source.

May it helps!