# Why is Expression Blend 4 not finding resources that are in a global Resource Library

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, styles

For some reason with this WPF project, I am getting the following exception in Blend:

[image]

This happens when one `UserControl` is inside another `UserControl` or `Window`.  `ItemBorder` is a style that exists in a Resource Library linked to the application XAML file.  It doesn't matter where I move this resource or its library.  Even if I put it directly into the `UserControl` that is using it, I get this exception.  Only when I make it a local value and not a resource does this exception go away.  This exception only happens in Blend.  It doesn't happen in Visual Studio (i'm using 2010), and it doesn't occur when I run the application.

I'm at the end of my rope here.  This problem means I am completely unable to use Expression Blend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried making it a dynamic resource?

I am not especially clear on the rules in play that determine Static vs Dynamic even give the answer below, but It has resolved a lot of issues for me when loading resources to change it from a Static to Dynamicresource.

[What's the difference between StaticResource and DynamicResource in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf)

Alright, after a little digging, [**I found this**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/f9cbcca1-1087-4fe7-ba6e-2968bfd9ede9).  The OP in this post has a situation quite similar to yours.  His work around suggests merging resource dictionaries at the Usercontrol level rather than only through App.xaml.

Comment: A dynamic resource is simply one that can be changed after it is set.  I suppose that I could try this, but I know that it is resource intensive to make your resources dynamic, so its not really a solution for my project.

Comment: I haven't had a case when I changed resources after setting them, but I still have resources that are referred to through DynamicResource often enough.  When you referenced the resource in Blend did you do so through the GUI or hand jam it?

Comment: This is a project started before we had blend.  So a lot of it is manual yes.  After using blend with other projects, I never want to go back to that.

Comment: Any possibility that you could remove the resource call (just comment it out temporarily if you like) and try and find the resource through the Blend GUI.

Comment: Did that. I even moved (through the Blend GUI) the resource into the file that was using it, and it still gave me the in designer exception.

Comment: I think that my problem was probably similar to this. I fixed my problem differently.  I had a user control inside of a template that was in its own resource dictionary.  I think it was an artifact of the days before Expression Blend; I think I thought I had to have a separate template in order to show custom items in a list control.  I removed the template "middle-man" and everything works well.   Thanks