# How can I access a dynamic resource from a different assembly inside a ViewBase

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, .net-assembly, dynamicresource

I am working with a Xaml file that is a custom view derived from a ViewBase, and I would like to access a DynamicResource that is in a different assembly. I have seen that it is possible to use something like:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary
    Source="/mylib;Resources/MyStyleDictionary.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

However I'm dealing with a xaml file that looks something like:

```
<myLib:ViewBase> 
    <Grid>
        <Button>
            Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}" // I want this style to come from a different assembly
        </Button>
    </Grid>
 </myLib:ViewBase>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand the difference between Dynamic and Static resources. [What's the difference between StaticResource and DynamicResource in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf)

But to answer the question:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/SomeOtherAssembly;Resources/SomeOtherDictionaryWithMyButtonStyleKey.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/mylib;Resources/MyStyleDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The resource is being referenced dynamically, so merging SomeOtherDictionaryWithMyButtonStyleKey.xaml before merging in MyStyleDictionary.xaml should work.

Comment: Thank-you, but where would this Application.Resources be placed? I am working with a ViewBase xaml, and I do not have an App.xaml in this project

Comment: at whatever resource level makes sense. Resources is a property on FrameworkElement.