# Regarding usage of binding: WPF Solid Color Brushes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl that defines a Grid Like this :

```
<Grid ClipToBounds="True"
      x:Name="GHeader"
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="0"
      Background="{DynamicResource BrushRoomHeaderBackground}"
      >
```

The following styles are defined in ResourceDictionary which are loaded at the start:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushRoomHeaderBackground" 
                 Color="{DynamicResource ColorPassive}"
                 /> 

<Color x:Key="ColorPassive">#FF9499C0</Color>
```

Should DynamicResource binding be used or StaticResource ? 
Could there be any memory leak here ?

Comment: See this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

As explained Manish you should have a look on his link to have a better understanding of the difference between Static and Dynamic ressource.

The short story is:

- StaticResource are resolved during the loading of the XAML (only once even before application running)
- DynamicResource are resolved at runtime, and will be updated if the source dictionnary changed

So for you the question is: did you plan to update your dictionnary at runtime, or at least is your ressource defined after the grid declaration? If not, prefer StaticResource for clarity and performance.

Comment: The solidcolorbrush and the  Color in the resourcedictionary are not changed later in the code. they remain as defined.