# Wpf window title from static resource

Tags: wpf, dictionary, window, title

I am using resource dictionarys for localizations, I have this code in wpf:

```
<Window x:Class="RWIS_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="RWIS" Height="500" Width="800" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Localizations/Dictionary.EN.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

My problem is, that I want to localize window title using `{StaticResource mW_screen1}`

```
    <Window x:Class="RWIS_WPF.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

            Title="{StaticResource IT_IS_NOT_WORKING}" Height="500" Width="800"
            MinHeight="500" MinWidth="800">

            <Window.Resources>
              <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Localizations/Dictionary.EN.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             </ResourceDictionary>
            </Window.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource IT_IS_WORKING}"></TextBlock>
```

But it is not working, because resource is defined after title is calling it. It will give me error when I try to run it

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred   Message='Provide
>   value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.'
>   Line number '6' and line position '9'.

It is working for headers, text after adding resource

I have tried to call it in c# code, but i was not succesful.
I know there is option:

```
<Window.Title></Window.Title>
```

but there is no argument like text or value, where can i put `Text="{StaticResource IT_IS_WORKING}"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the more verbose definition of `StaticResource`:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

...

<Window.Resources>
    <System:String x:Key="Title">Some Title</System:String>
    ...
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Title>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Title" />
</Window.Title>
```

Answer (score 7):

`StaticResource` are applied at the time of loading of BAML (compiled XAML) into memory and it `parses XAML from top to bottom` and since your resource haven't created yet, it throws error while loading of XAML.

Instead, try using `DynamicResource` which is lazy loaded version you can say. It assigns an expression object to target property. This defers looking up the resource until it is needed at runtime.

Read this for further clarification - [StaticResource V/S DyanamicResource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200875/632337).

```
<Window Title="{DynamicResource IT_WILL_WORK}"/>
```

Comment: I know I'm being "that guy" right now but... This should be the accepted answer