# I can not apply the Style for custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, styles

I can not apply the Style for custom **UserControl**.
Styles for **TextBlock** and **MyControl** are in the same dictionary.
Style for **TextBlock** used without problems.
But for **MyControl** style is not applied.
Why?

> ```
> // XAML
> xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyControlNameSpace"
>
>  <Grid>
>    <TextBlock x:Name="text"  Style="{DynamicResource TextStyle}"/>
>    <local:MyControl x:Name="control" Style="{DynamicResource ControlStyle}"/>
>  </Grid>
>
> // RESOURCE DICTIONARY
>   <Style x:Key="ControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
>         <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
>         <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
>         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
>         <Setter Property="ColorMain" Value="Black"/>
>         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
>   </Style>
>
>   <Style x:Key="TextStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
>        ....
>        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32"/>
>        ...
>    </Style>
> ```

```
     //PART of CS           
     public partial class MyControl: UserControl   {    ....   }
```

Comment: this part looks fine , post the xaml of MyControl .

Comment: You're definitely using concrete instances of MyControl? Not sub classes of it?

Comment: Unless you are planning to make changes to your `Style`s at run time, you should [use `StaticResource` instead of `DynamicResource`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf).

Comment: GazTheDestroyer - Not sub class

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<Setter Property="ColorMain" Value="Black"/>
```

To

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
```