# How to specify default datatemplate as static resource in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a default template defined for one of my classes. It works correctly and is applied as I'd expect, but I am using an attached property (detailed [here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.UwS3mYVWrKc), actually) for which I have to specify a `DataTemplate`. I have been unable to find an acceptable way of specifying my default template in XAML.

My data template looks something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNS:MyType}">
    ....
</DataTemplate>
```

So far I have attempted to specify it like this

`attached:property.MyDataTemplate="{StaticResource {x:Type myNS:MyType}}"`

but this throws an exception at runtime ("Cannot find resource named 'My.Full.NameSpace.MyType'. Resource names are case sensitive.").

I've done enough looking around to know that other people have similar problems but I haven't been able to find a decent solution. I am considering simply maintaining a duplicate `DataTemplate` with an `x:Key` so I can point at it. Is there a better way?

UPDATE:

Alright - it's been pointed out that this does work if you use `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`. This does not make sense to me.

I've read a fair bit on DynamicResource vs StaticResource (among other thing, I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf)). Here's what I do know:

- If I specified a `x:Key` instead of a `DataType` I can use this template as a `StaticResource`.
- When the page loads the template is in the dictionary and can be retrieved in code

  `var myTemplate = this.Resources[new DataTemplateKey(typeof(MyType))];`

Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: Have you already tried `attached:property.MyDataTemplate="{DynamicResource {x:Type myNS:MyType}}"` ? and does it work. cos I'm not sure if `StaticResource` would even work for this.

Comment: OMG. Yes. Yes, it does work as `DynamicResource`.

Comment: Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Do you happen to know why that works? It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try: (Switch `StaticResource` to `DynamicResource`)

```
attached:property.MyDataTemplate="{DynamicResource {x:Type myNS:MyType}}"
```

My **guess** for the reason why this works:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200875/1834662) gives a good difference between `StaticResource` and `DynamicResource`. I'm guessing this Default template data isn't available when `StaticResource` tries to retrieve it(during the loading of the XAML) which isn't the case for `DynamicResource`

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the problem because of your `DataTemplate` has `DataTemplateKey` with type `myNS:MyType`, but `property.MyDataTemplate="{StaticResource {x:Type myNS:MyType}}"` tries to find resource with string key matching your type full name.

Instead of using `"{StaticResource {x:Type myNS:MyType}}"` you should use:

`"{StaticResource {DataTemplateKey {x:Type myNS:MyType}}}"`

or its full equivalent:

`"{StaticResource ResourceKey={DataTemplateKey DataType={x:Type myNS:MyType}}}"`.

Also, you don't need `DynamicResource` in this case.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the accepted answer!