# Set DataTemplate control Style code behind

Tags: wpf, styles, datatemplate

So ia have this `ListView` with Custom `Column` `Progress-Bar`:

```
            <ListView Name="lvFiles">        
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <ProgressBar 
                                Name="progressBarColumn"
                                Maximum="100"
                                Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" 
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar}" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=progressBarColumn, StringFormat={}{0:N1}%}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                FontSize="11.5"
                                Foreground="White"
                                Margin="0,-2,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>                        
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ProgressBarTemplate">
                        <Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text }"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.Resources>                    
            </ListView>
```

Style

```
<Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar" >
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF103766" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF103766" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Value="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ProgressBar}}">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightSeaGreen"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So in case i want to create several `Styles` and change this `Style` from code behain, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

One line of code can do that:

```
  progressBarColumn.Style = (Style)Application.Current.TryFindResource("CustomProgressBar");
```

When you have multiple custom Progress Bar styles, you just replace "CustomProgressBar" in the code above with whatever the name of your desired progress bar style actually is.

Make sure that your Styles are in a dictionary (or location) that is visible at the application level.

Comment: i cannot reach progressBarColumn from code, my style is inside Styles folder under application root and i have add this the App.xaml: <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/ProgressBar.xaml" />

Comment: Where i need to put this ?

Comment: Replace with what ?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148544/discussion-between-stewbob-and-user979033).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `DynamicResource` markup extension:

```
Style="{DynamicResource CustomProgressBar}" />
```

...you could easily switch *the resource* at runtime:

```
lvFiles.Resources["CustomProgressBar"] = Application.Current.Resources["yourOtherStyle"] as Style;
```

[What's the difference between StaticResource and DynamicResource in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf)

Comment: Did you try this or what happened? Please accept answers to your questions.