# How do I set a primary color that I can use for my background property in ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So I created a `ResourceDictionary` that looks like this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryColor" Color="#252525"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now my question is how do I get a hold of that key so I can use it for my `background` property on my MainWindow?

```
<Window ...
        Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to merge the `ResourceDictionary` into your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="YourResourceDict.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Once it's in scope, you could reference any resource using either `{DynamicResource key}` or `{StaticResource key}`

[What's the difference between StaticResource and DynamicResource in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf)

Comment: I forgot to add that into the question but I actually did merge it into my `App.xml` and I am trying to use `Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"` which didnt work nor did `Background="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"`

Comment: Are you getting an error when you use `StaticResource` or what happens? What's the contents of the window?

Comment: Nevermind, I am using Visual Studio 2019 RC and It didnt display the error message I was getting in another file, the issue is resolved thanks! I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes.