# StaticResource error : `{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property

Tags: c#, wpf

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I have my `Colors` defined in a `ResourceDictionary` : `Colors.xaml` :

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="Normal">#FF404040</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then used in `Brushes.xaml` :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml"/>
        <!-- here I may have more colors-->
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color" Color="{StaticResource Normal}" />
    <!-- here I may have more brushes-->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then `Brushes` are merged in `Generic.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes.xaml"/>
        <!-- here I may have more resources-->
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now if I use the `Brushes` in let say a `Border` `Style` like so :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="BorderContainer" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Color}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I must use it as `DynamicResource` but if used as `StaticResource` then I got this error at runtime :

`{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'Background'`

I wish to use StaticResource for Brushes everywhere in my app.

Comment: You should use `Brush` object for background instead of `Color` object, in your example `<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Color}"/>` (btw, your naming style isn't so good)

Comment: yes the naming is not really good, I'm in the process of redoing all that color things. I tried your solution and it's the same error.

Comment: Have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf  If you didn't set your resource directly from them _App.xaml_, you should use _DynamicResource_. _StaticResource_ is used during object construction

Comment: My Generic.xaml is a resource in App.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use StaticResource in your ResourceDictionary, you need to merge the Brushes.xaml ResourceDictionary into the ResourceDictionary where you define the Border style, like you did with Colors.xaml in Brushes.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <!-- "Include" Brushes -->
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style x:Key="BorderContainer" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Color}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

For more information on the difference between Static- and DynamicResource see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf).