# How to set dynamic and static resource at same time in Xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to assign both static and dynamic styles to a control at same time.
Something like this

```
<Button
  Style="{StaticResource homeScreenBackButton}"
  Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Metro.Styles.MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
    <Button.Content>
      <Image Source="wwwroot/images/homescreen-back2.png" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

I could easily achieve this

```
<Button
  Width="38"
  Height="38"
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  Cursor="Hand"
  Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Metro.Styles.MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
    <Button.Content>
      <Image Source="wwwroot/images/homescreen-back2.png" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

But I don't want to hardcode the styles in this way.

Comment: It would be useful to learn [what "StaticResource" and "DynamicResource" actually mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200875/424129).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you cannot set a single property like `Style` to two different values simultaneously. You can base a `Style` on another one though:

```
<Image x:Key="img" x:Shared="false" Source="wwwroot/images/homescreen-back2.png" />
<Style x:Key="homeScreenBackButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Metro.Styles.MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource img}" />
</Style>
```

**Usage:**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource homeScreenBackButton}" />
```