# How to use an object instantiated as a resource in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to instantiate a class defined in C# in XAML and use it in both XAML and code. I found out that I can instantiate the object as a resource and use TryFindResource("...") to locate it in code but I am confused about how I should reference it later in XAML. Fore example, I have the following XAML code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <localx:PipeViewModel x:Key="pipeview" />
</UserControl.Resources>


<DockPanel  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Background="White">
    <hx:HelixViewport3D x:Name="HelixViewport3D" 
                        ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" 
                        CameraRotationMode="Trackball" 
                        CameraMode="FixedPosition"
                        PanGesture="LeftClick">
        <hx:DefaultLights  />
        <hx:DefaultLights  />
        <localx:PipeViewModel x:Name="pipeview" MyPipeModel="{Binding Path=PipeModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1}}"/>
    </hx:HelixViewport3D>
</DockPanel>
```

I am not sure if the object instantiated in the resource section is the same one inserted in HelixVievPort3D. I suspect that using the same names doe not necessarily imply they are the same. How can I correctly insert the pipeview object in HelixViewPort?

Comment: A view model object would usually not be added to an element tree. You would instead assign it to the DataContext property of a view element to use it as the source of Bindings.

Comment: Clemens: Thank you for your feedback. I am sorry but I do not follow MVVM so strictly. As you may suspect from labels, my ViewModel object combines both the View and ViewModel. It does contain the visual element I want to insert it to the viewport. So my question is still open.

Comment: Sounds terrible. However, search StackOverflow for how to use StaticResourceExtension to use a UIElement resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, declaring elements like this creates **new** instances. This is called [*Object element syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#object-element-syntax). Consequently, the `PipeViewModel` declared in the resources section is a different instance than in the viewport.

> *Object element syntax* is the XAML markup syntax that instantiates a CLR class or structure by declaring an XML element.

In XAML, you can reference resources using the [`StaticResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/staticresource-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) or [`DynamicResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dynamicresource-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) markup extenstions. For the difference between both, you can refer to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf).

You should be able to use one of the markup extensions as tag to use the element in your viewport:

```
<hx:HelixViewport3D x:Name="HelixViewport3D" 
                    ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" 
                    CameraRotationMode="Trackball" 
                    CameraMode="FixedPosition"
                    PanGesture="LeftClick">
   <hx:DefaultLights/>
   <hx:DefaultLights/>
   <StaticResource ResourceKey="pipeview"/>
</hx:HelixViewport3D>
```

Since the instance in your resources is now the only one, you might want to add the binding there.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <localx:PipeViewModel x:Key="pipeview" MyPipeModel="{Binding Path=PipeModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

---

As you commented on your question, the `PipeViewModel` is a mixture of view model and view. I strongly recommend you to use MVVM for a clear separation of view, data and business logic, otherwise understanding, extending and maintaining your application will be hard in the long run.

Comment: thatguy: THANK you indeed very much for a very comprehensive response. Yes, indeed I had the binding in my code already exactly like you recommend. I will make my current design work first and then follow the other suggestions.